# How do i autofill angularjs input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying autofill a website using javascript.

This code

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[1].value = "MYNAME";
```

input text changing but when i click the submit button it says empty.

Please help me..

This is the html

`<div ng-app="VitaminMiddleSchoolApp" ng-controller="componentEbaEtudExternalEditViewController">`

`<input spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="none" class="form-control input-sm ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" type="text" ng-model="render.etudName" maxlength="60" ng-change="saveRenderer()" style="">`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` = NOPE. This is not how Angular works. You don't select elements in the DOM, and fill them with data. It's the opposite. You modify the data, and then Angular updates the DOM accordingly. Please take a few basic tutorials about Angular, or make your site with Javascript only and don't bother including Angular at all.

Comment: I am not building the website. working on existing website. And trying to autofill all options to make my job easier.

Comment: Then your work consists in _dropping Javascript DOM methods and start using Angular_. If you don't, you are going to have your hard time. You'll start using hacks, because what you think should work doesn't (typically, your current problem - it already started). Your application will grow full of hacks and workarounds and will get unmaintainable. This being said, you do what you will :)

Comment: In AngularJS, although I haven't practiced it since it died in 2016, it's just `$scope.render.etudName="whatever"`. Done. If you try to hack Angular and select DOM elements and modify them outside of Angular's knowledge, well, good luck with that. But again, it's your time and your application, so it's your choice.

Comment: I am a Social Studies Teacher in Turkey. we are doing online classes. And we are filling same form same inputs everyday. And i'm trying to automize that. so at least i hope so :)

Comment: Well in this case, I'm sorry my friend but I can't help you, for 2 reasons; 1. AngularJS is long dead and I haven't practiced it in ages, and 2. This code is not using Angular and is trying to hack it with DOM methods, so it requires finding workarounds and stuff :( I guess you have a long night ahead of you, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `scope.$apply()` after calling `document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[1].value = "MYNAME";` Because angular doesn't know about your autofilled inputs.

But better solution is to use angular model way. So for example if you want to autofill `<input type="text" ng-model="my_test_model">` you can just use `ng-init` directive : `<input type="text" ng-model="my_test_model" ng-init="my_test_model='test_value'">` or assign it in the angular controller `scope.my_test_model='test_value'`

Comment: Man, you need to read a little about using angularjs for your development flow :) You need to add scope or $scope to your controller. Here is example of typical controller:
`myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.render = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[1].value = "MYNAME";
  $scope.apply()
}
  
}]);`

Comment: `after calling document.getElementsByClassName` I completely disagree. OP has to drop Javascripts DOM selectors and methods, and use Angular. Or stop using Angular, and use Javascript DOM methods. But not both.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance :) myApp.controller is VitaminMiddleSchoolApp.controller to me. Correct?

Comment: if you can create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for you app I can help you

Comment: Could you look at the jsfiddle

Comment: you provided html file only, I don't see any angular js files. You need to create working jsfiddle. where you'd like to autofill your input?

Comment: Yeah. Because im working a existing website. Using javascript to autofill blanks. Is that not possible?

Comment: Please accept the answer for stack overflow community if you think its answered.